# Python 2.7 ply.yacc generates "cannot get source" error in pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-2.7

I "inherited" a python app from a person who already left the company and now I'm having hard time getting it to work outside the obscure setup he had in his own box.

Basically I have gone through everything to make it compile nicely and gathered all the necessary modules so there are no problems. It runs beautifully from python. However the compiled version gives me this:

```
LOADER: executable is C:\DSLR\v4\source\dist\SUAT\SUAT.exe
LOADER: homepath is C:\DSLR\v4\source\dist\SUAT
LOADER: _MEIPASS2 is NULL
LOADER: archivename is C:\DSLR\v4\source\dist\SUAT\SUAT.exe
LOADER: No need to extract files to run; setting extractionpath to homepath
LOADER: Already in the child - running user's code.
LOADER: manifestpath: C:\DSLR\v4\source\dist\SUAT\SUAT.exe.manifest
LOADER: Activation context created
LOADER: Activation context activated
LOADER: Python library: C:\DSLR\v4\source\dist\SUAT\python27.dll
LOADER: Manipulating evironment
LOADER: PYTHONPATH=C:\DSLR\v4\source\dist\SUAT
LOADER: PYTHONHOME=C:\DSLR\v4\source\dist\SUAT
LOADER: Manipulating Python's sys.path
LOADER: importing modules from CArchive
LOADER: extracted struct
LOADER: extracted pyi_os_path
LOADER: extracted pyi_archive
LOADER: extracted pyi_importers
LOADER: Installing import hooks
LOADER: out00-PYZ.pyz
LOADER: Running scripts
Filename is C:\DSLR\v4\source\dist\SUAT\enaml\core\parser.pyc
Sourcefile is C:\DSLR\v4\source\dist\SUAT\enaml\core\parser.py
ERROR:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 43, in <module>
  File "C:\DSLR\v4\source\build\SUAT\out00-PYZ.pyz\enaml", line 61, in imports
  File "c:\users\olli~1.man\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-9rafnl\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 2
70, in load_module
  File "C:\DSLR\v4\source\build\SUAT\out00-PYZ.pyz\enaml.core.import_hooks", line 18, in <module>
  File "c:\users\olli~1.man\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-9rafnl\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyi_importers.py", line 2
70, in load_module
  File "C:\DSLR\v4\source\build\SUAT\out00-PYZ.pyz\enaml.core.parser", line 3931, in <module>
  File "C:\DSLR\v4\source\build\SUAT\out00-PYZ.pyz\ply.yacc", line 3273, in yacc
  File "C:\DSLR\v4\source\build\SUAT\out00-PYZ.pyz\ply.yacc", line 2931, in validate_all
  File "C:\DSLR\v4\source\build\SUAT\out00-PYZ.pyz\ply.yacc", line 2975, in validate_modules
  File "C:\DSLR\v4\source\build\SUAT\out00-PYZ.pyz\inspect", line 692, in getsourcelines
  File "C:\DSLR\v4\source\build\SUAT\out00-PYZ.pyz\inspect", line 540, in findsource
IOError: could not get source code
LOADER: RC: -1 from suat
LOADER: OK.
LOADER: Deactivating activation context
LOADER: Releasing activation context
LOADER: Done
LOADER: Cleaning up Python interpreter.
```

Filename and sourcefile are print statements I added to the inspector module to figure out what's going on. And, yes, those sourcefiles indeed are not in that dist folder. What's nasty here is that as far as I can tell, there's absolutely nothing in the SUAT.py that addresses source in any way or changes the os directory.

How would I deal with something like this? I've been googling until my eyes bleed for the last few days.. I have no idea why ply.yacc would go looking for the source file a compiled folder as the sources are not expected to be there to start with. FWIW, I'm using latest PLY (3.6) and ENAML (0.9.8). In desperation I got python(x y) and installed basically everything but it didn't change a thing. I've installed mingw64 as I ran into the "api version already set to '1'" issue earlier and needed functioning SIP to change the api file in a runtime hook..

As far as I can tell the paths are all pointing to correct places and pythonpath is set up as it should be.

```
C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\opencv\build\x86\vc10\bin;C:\PYTHON27\opencv\build\python\2.7;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;c:\windows\system32\downlevel;C:\mingw-w64\i686-5.2.0-posix-dwarf-rt_v4-rev0\mingw32\bin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I ended up editing the SPEC file to copy the relevant source files from python site-packages. Not too stylish but it works for a single folder build. Enaml definitely should not go trolling for py-files in a stand-alone built. I'm just not sure the return of investment of digging out just *why* these particular libraries are sought as .py files while the rest is checked as .pyd is worth it.