# Pyinstaller and Ply IOError: source code not available

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller, ply

I am pretty new to pyinstaller but I have been banging my head against this problem for a couple of days now and I can't seem to figure out what's wrong. My script runs fine normally but throws IOerror when i try to build with pyinstaller, my modules (including ply.lex) seem to be included but maybe i'm being an idiot? If anyone has any advice it would be much appreciated...

Here's my error (line 65 is where my lexer is built)

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 65, in <module>
  File "site-packages/ply/lex.py", line 906, in lex
  File "site-packages/ply/lex.py", line 580, in validate_all
  File "site-packages/ply/lex.py", line 822, in validate_rules
  File "site-packages/ply/lex.py", line 833, in validate_module
  File "inspect.py", line 690, in getsourcelines
  File "inspect.py", line 529, in findsource
IOError: source code not available
```

If anyone has seen this problem before, or can help that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLY insists that its grammars be defined in *files*. Real files, with names and everything. I think that's because of its strategy to cache the computed grammar tables, which involves comparing the timestamp of the cached tables with the timestamp of the original file.

Pyinstaller is, apparently, evaluating the grammar as a `<string>`, since it is extracted from an archive rather than being a file. (The Pyinstaller manual mentions that `__file__` is not correctly set for the frozen application, and that is what PLY is looking at.) You might try using the `--onedir` option when you create your installer bundle, but of course that has slightly different behaviour.

Comment: Thanks, maybe I wasn't specific enough or I have a misconception about the way lex operates.  I know yacc generates cached tables but I didn't think that lex did? I'm actually not using yacc as it's more than I need. I'm just tokenizing in lex and have done functions to order the output.  I have tried --onedir to no avail but I will have a more in depth look at it to see if it can help....

Comment: @blackmetalmcdonalds: regardless, PLY insists that `__file__` be the correct module path. Even if there is no good reason. I don't know much about pyinstaller, but basically you need to figure out how to get it to provide a usable `__file__`

Answer (score 0):

it seems that with PLY it is necessary to include the py file itself
as described on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522761/python-2-7-ply-yacc-generates-cannot-get-source-error-in-pyinstaller) link,  the workaround solution is to add the file in the .spec file generated by pyinstaller as below :

```
datas=[('calc.py','.')]
```

see pyinstaller Using spec file for details on adding a file into your executable