# Pyinstaller: add custom module with ply as a dependence

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, pyinstaller

I have a custom package, an egg installed in virtualenv and saved also in binaries folder. I tried to use it inside a program with pyinstaller. My spec looks like this:

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
             pathex=['/[...]/myproject', '/[...]/virtualenv/My_Library-3.18.1-py3.5.egg'],
             [...])
hiddenimports=['mylibrary', 'mylibrary.providers', 'mylibrary.tools'],
```

But when I put in the code:

```
import mylibrary as external
```

It gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    import mylibrary as external
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 968, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 957, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `mylibrary` to hiddenimports in your spec file.

```
hiddenimports = [mylibrary]
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I didn't paste all the trace, at the end it finished with:

```
File "/home/clara/enviroments/egggui/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller-3.4-py3.5.egg/PyInstaller/loader/pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages/pdfminer3k-1.3.1-py3.5.egg/pdfminer/pslexer.py", line 138, in <module>
File "site-packages/ply-3.8-py3.5.egg/ply/lex.py", line 906, in lex
File "site-packages/ply-3.8-py3.5.egg/ply/lex.py", line 580, in validate_all
File "site-packages/ply-3.8-py3.5.egg/ply/lex.py", line 822, in validate_rules
File "site-packages/ply-3.8-py3.5.egg/ply/lex.py", line 833, in validate_module
File "inspect.py", line 936, in getsourcelines
File "inspect.py", line 767, in findsource
OSError: could not get source code
[17622] Failed to execute script main
```

I did a research of lex.py line 833 and I found a bug for version 3.8: https://github.com/dabeaz/ply/issues/97 So **I updated ply to version 3.9 and error disapeared**.

If you can't upgrade ply to version 3.9, some people said something of adding the file to spec, but I didn't get it... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35589881/pyinstaller-and-ply-ioerror-source-code-not-available) is the question where they gave that advice.